# Error compiling with gfortran/gcc: crt1.o: In function `_start'

Tags: linux, linker, libraries, porting, gfortran

I'm executing this [makefile](http://pastebin.com/s6QNUwQJ) to compile a Fortran code using gfortran, gcc, netcdf and mpich2 libraries.

When the make script executes the following command,

```
gfortran   -O3  -I/home/santiago/Install/mpich2_sam/include -I/home/santiago/Install/netcdf_sam/include /home/santiago/Modeling/SAM6.8.2/SRC/fft.f
```

I get the following message:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In
>   function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have found similar error messages in forums, but I didn't saw how to apply the solutions in my problem.

Could someone please guide me solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you are building a library, you might need `-c` flag in

```
.f.o:
    ${FF77}  ${FFLAGS} $<
```

i.e.

```
.f.o:
    ${FF77}  ${FFLAGS} -c $<
```

The same applies for

```
.f90.o:
    ${FF90} ${FFLAGS} -c $<
.c.o:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -I$(SAM_SRC)/TIMING $(NOTIMERS) -c $<
```

Comment: It works. Every object file seems to be compiled. When trying to link the objects to build the executable, these messages are printed:
main.o: In function `main':
main.f90:(.text.startup+0x0): multiple definition of `main'

Comment: @PauloSantiago you may need to go through the source files to see if there is *main* function defined in multiple places.

Comment: @j-j-hakala, I could finally compile the program. After your help I found I made some mistakes (e.g., compiled libraries with ifort instead of gfortran). Thank you very much!